# How to replace NaNs using regression model estimates as forecasts

Tags: python, regression, nan, forecast

I have the following dataframe that shows monthly average daily volume of sales (adv) and average selling price (pkg_yld) and the 12-month percent changes for each metric:

df:

[image]

Over the period July 2021 to Dec. 2021 I need to:
(1) forecast pkg_yld using a linear regression model and then (2) calculate yoy_pkg_yld.

Both columns show NaN over the forecast horizon as shown above.

I have estimated a crude regression where Y = adv and X = pkg_yld;  estimated between July 2020 – June 2021:

```
X = df['adv']
y = df['pkg_yld']

X = sm.add_constant(X)
model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
model.summary()
```

The estimated regression is:
pkg_yld = 93.3 – 0.68 * adv

I want to enter the provided monthly ‘adv’ column values into the formula to populate a predicted monthly ‘pkg_yld’ for each month from July- Dec. 2021 and then calculate the yoy_pkg_yld over the same period.

```
For July 2021:
pkg_yld = 93.3 – (0.68 x 9.0) = 87.18
yoy_pkg_yld= ((87.2 / 97.5) -1 ) x 100 = -10.6%
```

And so on to Dec. 2021.
What is the simplest way to overwrite NaNs in the pkg_yld and yoy_pkg_yld columns with the estimated values in my existing dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

The first solution that I could come up with is defining a custom function which takes a series as an input and calculates the missing values if they are NaN. Then apply this function to every row of the DataFrame with `df.apply`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# setup example dataframe

data = {
        "A": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "B": [4, 6, np.nan, 35],
        "C": [np.nan, 7, np.nan, 1]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Function to apply on each row
# Insert your column names and coefficients
def func(row):
    if np.isnan(row["B"]):
        row["B"] = row["A"] * 0.5 + 3
    if np.isnan(row["C"]):
        row["C"] = row["A"] * 0.7 + 15
    return row

result = df.apply(func, axis=1) #Apply the function, axis=1 defines to apply on rows
```

You can also add positional or keyword arguments to `func` and pass them to the `values` argument of `apply` or directly as keyword arguments. Have a look into the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for further details.

Alternatively you yould compute all the regression results in advance and fill the missing values with `df.fillna` where necessary

```
import copy

values = copy.deepcopy(df) # copy df to avoid overriding existing values
values["B"] = values["A"] * 0.5 + 3
values["C"] = values["A"] * 0.7 + 15

result = df.fillna(value=values)
```

The second approach is more readable IMO, however you are calculating all possible results, which could be a lot less efficient than the first approach, depending on the complexity of your calculation and size of your dataframe.